# Unity want to get gameobjects from another array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have an array that gets all the gameobjects with the enemyMelee tag and i want to put the ones that have the idEnemy equal to the idDestination in another array.

How can i do this?

The maybeBlobsEnemy is the array that has all of them and blobsEnemy is the array that i want with only the condition above

[image: arrays visualized]

Here is my code

```
void Update()
{
    maybeBlobsEnemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("blobMelee");
    for (int i = 0; i < maybeBlobsEnemy.Length; i++)
    {
        if (maybeBlobsEnemy[i].GetComponent<BlobBehavior>().idBlob == idDestination)
        {
            blobsEnemy[i] = maybeBlobsEnemy[i];
        }

    }
```

Thank you for you time

Comment: `using System.Linq;
...

blobsEnemy = maybeBlobsEnemy.Where(item => item.GetComponent<BlobBehavior>().idBlob == idDestination).ToArray();
`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :D.
I would have never been able to do that

Comment: [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where), or simply use a `List<GameObject>` instead of an array, use your code and do `blobsEnemy.Add(maybeBlobsEnemy[i]);` instead ... in all cases: **Do not do this in `Update`** ... it is very expensive